# thingsboard dashboard, dashbord, gauges

Tags: dashboard, thingsboard

Hi i am trying to create an dashboard in thingsboard, so my telemetry data is a Json
{
"temperature": 42.2,
"humidity": 70,
"hvacEnabled": true,
"hvacState": "IDLE",
"config": {
"svm": 42,
"dps": 89
}
}

I am receiving this data in thingsboard telemetry, after that i created dashboard with this data, i can assign gauges to temperature and humidity, but i am unable to attach svm and dps to any gauges. data source is showing config as a topic but i cant further goes to svm and dps.

Can anyone suggest me how can i assign gauges to sub topic ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract `svm` and `dps` keys from nested object `config`

One of the right ways is to use [Script Transformation Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/transformation-nodes/#script-transformation-node) in your Rule Chain to transform `"config": { "svm": 42, "dps": 89 }` to, e.g:

```
"config_svm": 42,
"config_dps": 89
```